# Display palette (coloramp) imagery in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, sld

I have a data set of palette imagery. These are basically RGB imagery that have been converted to 1 band color map imagery using ArcGIS.

I am loading the images to GeoServer as GeoTIFFs but nothing is being displayed in OpenLayers, it is just blank white page. I was wondering if this has to do with their style file, or am I missing something else?

Comment: How are you attempting to view the images with OpenLayers? I mean are you trying to view a TIFF in a browser? or do you have a WMS using the GeoTIFF as a datasource.  What request is sent to GeoServer from your OpenLayers client?

Comment: In GeoServer's "Layer Preview" there is an option of OpenLayes..
That's what I was referring to.
And When I cache a Tiff file using GeoWebCache and create a WMTS, the result is still white and blank.

Comment: You should edit your question to add those details.  There is still a request being sent to the GeoServer server, which you can capture.  I'm still not clear from your response whether you are requesting a TIFF or not.  TIFFs generally don't display in a browser, doesn't matter what the palette is.

Comment: how did you add the tiff to geoserver, what style did you apply? Does the coverage band info on the layer page show that it is palletted?

Comment: Try to change WMS style. From Layers--> Publishing Tab--> WMS style.

Comment: @nmtoken Sorry for the delayed response, I am requesting a TIFF in this case, however, when I use the same image in RGB, I can display it without any problems in OpenLayers, that's why I assumed there may be something (like Style file) that I am missing,

Comment: @IanTurton Yes, in the layer page it shows that it is palleted.
Also, I have used a number of style samples from Geoserver's SLD cookbook just to be able to display "Something", but all I am getting is blank white result.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer this without access to your data file, but when I add a palleted geotif to GeoServer I see the following on the layer page under coverage parameters:

[image]

I use a simple style to just set a minimum and maximum scale to display at and everything works just fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld
http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" version="1.0.0">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>ras250</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>A raster style</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <MinScaleDenominator>15001</MinScaleDenominator>
          <MaxScaleDenominator>300000</MaxScaleDenominator>
          <RasterSymbolizer>
            <Opacity>1.0</Opacity>
          </RasterSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```